# How to convert the date values field on flat file as header columns within SSIS

Tags: ssis

I am trying to upload multiple CSV files which has dates but I wanted the dates to be part of the column and I have no idea how its done in SSIS

CSV files look as shown below when opened in Excel.

#### CSV data 1:

```
Relative Date: 02/01/2013
Run Date: 15/01/2013

Organisation,AreaCode,ACount
Chadwell,RM6,50
Primrose,RM6,60
```

#### CSV data 2:

```
Relative Date: 14/02/2013
Run Date: 17/02/2013

Organisation,AreaCode,ACount
Second Ave,E12,110
Fourth Avenue, E12,130
```

In the Data Warehouse, I want the *`Relative Date`* and *`Run Date`* along the columns as shown below:

#### Desired output:

```
| Organisation   | AreaCode | ACount | RelativeDate | RunDate    |
| ------------   | -------- | ------ | ------------ | ---------- |
| Second Avenue  |  E12     |  110   |  14/02/2013  | 17/02/2013 |
| Fourth Avenue  |  E12     |  130   |  14/02/2013  | 17/02/2013 |
| Chadwell       |  RM6     |  50    |  02/01/2013  | 15/01/2013 |
| Primrose       |  RM6     |  60    |  02/01/2013  | 15/01/2013 |
```

Comment: You will have to import the file using a script. Either a script task in the control flow (my preference) or a script source component in a data flow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would add a Script Task to the control flow, presumably within a Foreach Loop Container to cycle through the files.  The Script task would read the dates from the first two rows and shred them into Variables.

Then in the Flat File Source definition I would tell it to skip the first 3 lines.  Finally in the Data Flow I would add a Derived Column transformation to add the two required columns from the date Variables.

Comment: What would I write in the Script task as I have no idea.